# PHP/SQL Voting and counting up the results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, vote

I am writing a script for a car show. Users choose the car number and vote 1-5 on various criteria. There are multiple users voting for the same car, but they can only vote once for each car, I check for this.

Now I have a table of a unique carNumber and 1-5 votes for each criteria, per car.

Here is how I find the total score for each individual users vote

```
SELECT carNum, exterior+interior+engine AS Score FROM Judge_Votes WHERE catagory = '$catNum' ORDER BY carNum

Reults 
CarNum: Score:
18  11
14  8
13  15
12  8
12  11
2   14
```

I want to add up the total score from each user into a final score result. IE car 12 has 19 total score.

The question I have. How can I find the total score using sql or php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use SUM and ORDER BY:

```
SELECT carNum, SUM(exterior+interior+engine) AS Score 
    FROM Judge_Votes 
    WHERE catagory = '$catNum' 
    GROUP BY carNum
```

That should do the "trick"

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT carNum, sum(exterior + interior + engine) as Score 
FROM Judge_Votes 
WHERE gatagory = '$catNum' 
GROUP BY carNum 
ORDER BY carNum
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick I think. The logic is that you group your result per car (GROUP BY carNum) and then use the build in SUM function of SQL.

```
SELECT SUM(exterior+interior+engine) as totalScore, carNum 
FROM Judge_Votes 
WHERE catagory = '$catNum' 
GROUP BY carNum
ORDER BY carNum;
```